# time stamp in tcpdump file

Tags: timestamp, tcpdump

I have written a linux script to dump the packets using tcpdump command to a file dcn.pcap to max limit of 20MB. Is there anyway to add the timestamp to the filename ? The time stamp from the beginning of the file like  2014_date_time.pcap

```
tcpdump -w dcn.pcap -C 20 -i eth0 -s 65535 dst net 244.11.11
```

Comment: Aren't your captured packets showing a timestamp for each one?
Or do you mean adding timestamps to the file*name*?

Comment: @James yes, time stamp to the file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, just like this(assume you use bash and have superuser privileges to use tcpdump):

```
date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S' | xargs -I {} bash -c "tcpdump -C 20 -i eth0 -s 65535 dst net 244.11.11 -w ./{}.pcap"
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on jify's answer, you can simplify it a bit with shell-substitution, negating the need for `xargs`, like so:

`tcpdump -C 20 -i eth0 -s 65535 dst net 244.11.11 -w $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)_dcn.pcap`

This would produce a file like **2016-03-10_22:10:58_dcn.pcap**

The various quotes are also not strictly necessary, and I've omitted them for clarity in this example. Use your best judgement as to if you need them in your particular situation.